# Average of a set of probability measures

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Given an integer $n\ge 1$, let 
$
\textstyle \Delta:=\left\{x \in [0,1]^n: \sum_{i\le n}x_i=1\right\}
$ 
be the $n-1$-dimensional simplex. Consider a random variable 
$
X: \Omega\to \Delta
$ 
(on a measurable space $\Omega$) with the uniform distribution on $\Delta$, let us say $\mathrm{Pr}$ (in other words, this is the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)).

At this point, fix reals $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots,a_n,b_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{i\le n}a_i \le 1$ and $a_i< b_i$ for all $i$, and define
$$
R:=\left\{x \in \Delta: a_i\le x_i\le b_i \text{ for all }i=1,\ldots,n\right\}.
$$

> **Question.** Is there a "reasonable" way to compute the expected value of $X$, given that $X \in R$? In other words, is it possible to compute (as function of the parameters $a_i,b_i$) the value of 
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}[\,X\,|\,R\,]:=\frac{1}{\mathrm{Pr}(R)}\int_{\omega \in \Omega:\, X(\omega) \in R} X(\omega)\,\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{d}\omega)\quad?
> $$